# Perl Text::CSV::Slurp process the fixed width input

Tags: perl, text

I would like to parse the some text into a table which showing below:

```
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.35.195.1             -   0024.978a.d2d0  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.2            73   0002.16a3.9e40  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.12          130   0007.0e5b.861a  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.14            1   000b.cdc9.7d11  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.15            3   0021.5a7b.f2af  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.16            0   000c.2909.2298  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.17          112   0001.e6a2.5a90  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  10.35.195.24          168   0050.564b.ebd4  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
```

There are text inputs with fixed width. Some Params ,such as "Hardware Addr"， have whitespace in it. At the first, I use Text::CSV::Slurp, it is difficult to define separator. So i give up.

Just like to know, are there some perl modules or embedded perl command (unpack, substr）can process this input smoothly and efficiently?

Comment: `unpack` can process this, yes. And `substr` too. Why do you ask if you already know? Is there something about the documentation you don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [Parse::FixedLength](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Parse-FixedLength-5.39/FixedLength.pm) module, which handles properly this kind of problems. This is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parse::FixedLength;

#define your format in the constructor
my $pfl = Parse::FixedLength->new([qw(Protocol:10 Addr:34)], {trim=>1});

open my $file, '<', 'file_to_be_readed.txt' or die $!;
<$file> #if your file has a header, forget it

while( my $line = <$file> ) {
   my $data = $pfl->parse($line);
   my $protocol = $data->{Protocol};
   my $addr = $data->{Addr};
   #...
}

close $file;
```